# Copy excel 2010 sheet to another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have two copies of an Excel 2010 spreadsheet, my copy for editing and the master.  I have created a new sheet in my copy which acts as a statistics page, totaling up totals from all other sheets.  I wish to transfer this into the master copy.  If I use standard copy and paste or the Excel 'Move Sheet' function the formulae copy over but still reference my version of the spreadsheet.

Example

```
Spreadsheet1 =>   =sum('sheet1'!A:A)
Spreadsheet2 =>   =sum('[Spreadsheet1.xlsx]sheet1'!A:A)
```

Without having to manually go through the master version and edit each field can anyone suggest a way to copy this over without it trying to refer back to the original spreadsheet?

Comment: A possible duplicate : http://superuser.com/questions/171216/is-there-a-way-to-copy-an-excel-worksheet-without-copying-all-of-the-cell-styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution (quick n dirty): after copy and paste, replace "[Spreadsheet1.xlsx]" in the new sheet by an empty string